# Azure Webjob stops reading outgoing service bus messages with error Closing messaging factories

Tags: azureservicebus, nservicebus, azure-webjobs

We have an Azure webjob that reads messages from an Azure service bus queue using NServiceBus.
Four years ago we had an issue where the webjob abruptly stopped reading messages from the queue.
This has happened again on 11th Jan 2023.
Here is the log:

```
[11/07/2022 22:27:08 > 3eb1d6: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[11/07/2022 22:27:08 > 3eb1d6: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[11/07/2022 22:27:08 > 3eb1d6: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.Call(MethodInfo method)
[11/07/2022 22:27:08 > 3eb1d6: ERR ]    at Rock.Invoice.InvGateway.WebJobHost.Program.Main()
[11/07/2022 22:27:08 > 3eb1d6: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
[11/07/2022 22:27:08 > 3eb1d6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[11/07/2022 23:00:47 > 7b5dbd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/07/2022 23:51:47 > b9948f: INFO] 2022-11-07 23:51:47.223 INFO  NServiceBus.ForwardingTopology Closing messaging factories
[11/07/2022 23:51:47 > 7b5dbd: INFO] 2022-11-07 23:51:47.668 INFO  NServiceBus.ForwardingTopology Closing messaging factories
[11/08/2022 07:13:26 > b9948f: SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down
[11/08/2022 07:13:26 > b9948f: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[11/08/2022 07:13:26 > b9948f: ERR ] 
[11/08/2022 07:13:26 > b9948f: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
[11/08/2022 07:13:26 > b9948f: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[11/08/2022 07:13:26 > b9948f: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[11/08/2022 07:13:26 > b9948f: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Protocols.PersistentQueueWriter`1.<EnqueueAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
[11/08/2022 07:13:26 > b9948f: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

The only solution is to restart the webjob as discussed [here](https://discuss.particular.net/t/endpoint-on-azure-web-job-stops-processing-asb-queue/378).

Why does this error happen?

We are using NServiceBus.6.4.3 and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: A bit confused. You said it happened again on Jan 11, 2023, but the logs are from November 2022. Also, there is probably useful information in the log file above what you've provided. Regardless, it would probably be a good idea to open a proper support case with NServiceBus.

Comment: The issue was reported in January, although it happened in November.